# avr gcc inline asm variable input operand

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, avr

I want to be able to determine the port register for an inline asm function at runtime

```
asm(""::"I" (_SFR_IO_ADDR(PORTD)));
```

`_SFR_IO_ADDR` only accepts a constant

I have found these options but can't seem to pass register from variable.

```
asm(""::"m" (PORTD));
asm(""::"n" (&PORTD));
```

Thought this would be a common issue/request but can't seem to find any answers

Comment: The AVR `IN` instruction only supports immediate port number. You might want to try memory mapped access instead, if available.

Answer (score 0):

The AVR IN instruction only supports immediate port number. You might want to try memory mapped access instead, if available. – Jester